# How to program derivatives for recurrent weights

Tags: neural-network

I understand that the formula for the gradient of W and U is this: [image: figure 1]

How might I go around programming ds/dst-1 for example?

Comment: It is not very clear what you mean but if you are looking for the formulas of RNNs,I recommend you take a look at Alex Grave's implementation.

Comment: @Media the issue is I’m not sure how you would code ds/dst-1 specifically. Also would you be able to link me the the implementation as I cannot find it. Thank you

Comment: [here](https://github.com/szcom/rnnlib).

Answer (score 1):

Most deep learning frameworks use [automatic differentiation (AD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation) so it is handled for you.